# SharePoint 2013 workflow internal status suspended

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, suspend

I created a custom workflow in SharePoint and tested it and it worked great. Now when I add documents to the library that the workflow is attached to the status shows the workflow as being suspended. How can I fix this? Error message below.

```
RequestorId: 8af66be1-83bc-c13e-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 We&#39;re sorry, we weren&#39;t able to complete the operation, please try again in a few minutes. If you see this message repeatedly, contact your administrator. {"SPRequestGuid":["8af66be1-83bc-c13e-90bf-29cbfd70fe2b"],"request-id":["8af66be1-83bc-c13e-90bf-29cbfd70fe2b"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"SPRequestDuration":["448"],"SPIisLatency":["0"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4420"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Date":["Fri, 30 May 2014 19:43:09 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS\/8.0"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was resolved, tasks were not started and fell past due date. This caused the workflow to suspend itself. Terminated the workflow action, and that cleared it up immediately.